# What are the parametric equations for the following curve?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The curve with equation
$100x^2y^2 + x^2 + y^2 = 1$
looks like an astroid but is not apparently an astroid.

What are the parametric equations for this curve?

Please explain step by step if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the equivalent equality
$$ x^2 + (\sqrt{ 1 + 100 x^2}\cdot  y)^2 = 1$$ hence take 
$$\begin{align}x &= \cos \theta \\ y &=\frac{ \sin \theta}{ \sqrt{ 1 + 100 \cos^2 \theta} } \end{align}$$ with $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$.

Answer (score 2):

$$ 
100x^2y^2 + x^2 + y^2 
= 
1 
\Longleftrightarrow 
\\ 
100x^2y^2 + x^2 + y^2 + \dfrac{1}{100} 
= 
1 + \dfrac{1}{100} 
\Longleftrightarrow 
\\ 
(10x^2+\dfrac{1}{10})(10y^2+\dfrac{1}{10}) 
= 
\dfrac{101}{100} 
\ \ \ \ \ \ 
\color{Red}{\star} 
$$

---

---

Notice that we have:

$$ 
\dfrac{1}{10} 
\leq 
10x^2+\dfrac{1}{10} 
\ \ \ 
\text{and} 
\ \ \ 
\dfrac{1}{10} 
\leq 
10y^2+\dfrac{1}{10}; 
$$

the second inequlity is equivalent to $\dfrac{1}{10y^2+\dfrac{1}{10}} \leq 10$; 
so we have:

$$ 
(10x^2+\dfrac{1}{10}) 
\overset{\color{Red}{\star}}{=} 
\dfrac{101}{100}.\dfrac{1}{10y^2+\dfrac{1}{10}} 
\leq 
\dfrac{101}{100}.10 
= 
\dfrac{101}{10}; 
 $$

so we can conclude $(10x^2+\dfrac{1}{10}) \in [\dfrac{1}{10}, \dfrac{101}{10}]$.

---

---

Now let $t \in [\dfrac{1}{10}, \dfrac{101}{10}]$ be arbitrary, 
and let $10x^2+\dfrac{1}{10}=t$; 
by replacing in $\color{Red}{\star}$, 
we get the system of equations:

$$ 
             \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             10x^2+\dfrac{1}{10}=t , \\
             10y^2+\dfrac{1}{10}=\dfrac{101}{10t} , \\
             \end{array}
             \right.
$$ 
Solving this system of equations give us the following parametric solution:
$$(x,y)=(\pm \dfrac{\sqrt{10t-1}}{10},\pm \dfrac{\sqrt{101-t}}{10\sqrt{t}}).$$

Comment: Thanks, but the numerator of the $y$ solution is $\sqrt{101-t}$ for the system of equations, and the parametric solution doesn't satisfy the equation of the curve.

Comment: @George Nm1 ; Yes you are right, I am mistaken .The right value for $y$ is equal to $\dfrac{\sqrt{101-t}}{10\sqrt{t}}$, I have edited the answer.

Comment: This formula gives just a bit of the curve

Comment: @Raffaele ; Yes you are right, I have edited the answer a bit.